# How to specify which NSView to draw on in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I found this example of drawing a rectangle in objective-c cocoa

```
NSRect r = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 50, 60);
NSBezierPath *bp = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:r];
NSColor *color = [NSColor blueColor];
[color set];
[bp stroke];
```

However, where should I specify ***which*** NSView to draw on in the code?

For example, if I have two NSView objects, and I run this code, how do I specify which one to draw on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't run this code *on* an `NSView`, rather it runs *in* an `NSView` subclass's override of the `-drawRect:` method.

You'll need to create your own subclass of `NSView`, then in that subclass, override `-drawRect:` and put this code there:

```
@interface CustomView : NSView
@end

@implementation CustomView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect r = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 50, 60);
    NSBezierPath *bp = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:r];
    NSColor *color = [NSColor blueColor];
    [color set];
    [bp stroke];
}

@end
```

Finally, you will of course have to instantiate an instance of `CustomView` and add it to your view hierarchy, just as you would normally do with a regular `NSView`.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `NSView`, add your code to the `drawRect:` method of the subclass, and replace the appropriate `NSView` with an instance of your class.